# Windows 10: reset keyboard layouts possible?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

Solved, see below!

Is there a way to reset keyboard layouts in general in Windows 10?
I messed up using Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator some time ago, and I'm not able to fix it.
This is NOT something that can be fixed through anything in Language preferences, btw.

Last year, I was stupid enough to try to fix my keyboards on a "lower level".
I use the Norwegian and Korean keyboard a lot, sometimes also Japanese and Canadian French.
I have a hard time using symbols, like ";" - "'" - "~" etc, since these are placed differently on the various keyboards.

I looked for a solution, and found "Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator". I tried to fix the keyboards, but it didn't work that well since it had problems with the Korean keyboard. I thus tried to change the Norwegian keyboard somewhat, so that I would be able to write more efficiently, without always checking what keyboard I was using (the Korean one also has the American one ingrained, with a simple push of Alt-Gr).
I also have tried to make a shortcut to go from Norwegian to Korean and back seamlessly, without scrolling through other keyboards as well (Win+Shift scrolls through all available ones).
I don't remember exactly what I did, but it didn't really work out, so I thought I deleted the customized keyboards, and went back to the regular ones.
But there was a problem: one of the keys, VK_OEM_3, the one to the left of "L" to be exact, (";" on a regular US kezboard) no longer worked in Norwegian when used in a regular way. At first, it changed keyboard every time I used it to write regularly. I had set it up to do this when pushed WITH another key (probably AltGr), but something was not right.
I managed to delete the customized keyboards, deleted and reinstalled the Norwegian keyboard from Microsoft, but lo and behold, the key no longer worked. I.e, it works when I push it down for a long time, maybe half a second, and then I get a lot of "øøøø". When using TeamViewer, it dosn't even help to hold the key in for a long time. And the digital keyboard certainly does not work.
I have tried to download other keyboards, and the key works well for A-Z and symbols that exist on a US keyboard.
Thus, the French keyboard, where it is an "M", works well. As does US and Korean keyboard layouts where it is an ";".
But it works as badly for Danish layout, where it is an "Æ" or German layout, where it is an "Ö". Both of these layouts were downloaded for the first time after I had messed up.

I have tried kbdEdit, that made me end up with a German keyboard layout I had a hard time to get rid of, even though I deleted it multiple times from "Langauge preferences".
I haven't learned kbdEdit well though, so it might work out.
But I'm afraid that it might not work, and that I

But what has happened here? I used a Microsoft program, and thought that would be safe enough, even though I was warned it might not work, since it's old. But messing up one key completely...
I have deleted all the new keyboards from the Registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts), btw. But it's apparently on a lower level than this, since there are problems with all kinds of keyboards that have "extended Latin" letters on that place.)

What I wonder, is if there is a file that can be replaced with a standard file. I don't really want to reinstall Windows and my hundreds of programs, but I can hardly work in Norwegian the way things are now.
I have to check the phrases for eventual missing "ø", and when I remember the problem, it stops my flow since I have to push down for a long time and then delete the extra "øøø"s.

Comment: May be you should ask this in `superuser`. Stack Overflow is only for programming.

Comment: Save your important files, reset the operating system

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to fix the problem:

Under registry keys, in my case in multiple  locations, there is a map called SYSTEM\KeyboardLayout\Substitutes.
I deleted everything but the default one in all of these, and now it works!